# Can I flash boot.img of a MIUI rom to a different MIUI rom?

Tags: miui

Can I flash boot.img of a MIUI rom to a different MIUI rom which is an updated version of the same MIUI rom (MIUI 8.0.2.0 boot.img to 8.1.0.0 )?
Both roms are based on the same android version and for the same device..

Comment: Back up and try, doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, bad move. You have literally nothing to gain from doing this, and depending on the device you have, your worst case scenario is an unrecoverable paperweight if things go wrong. I've bricked a few Kindle Fires like this. Even if it doesn't brick it, you will still probably have to do a restore of the old boot.img because it may well be incompatible with your Android ROM (there is probably a reason why the bootloader got an update bundled with the rest of the new ROM). Honestly I wouldn't risk it. Don't do it.

Comment: I flashed it and bootloop lol. 
Thankfully I had nandroid backup and restored my rom. 
Thanks for your help guys.. 

Curiosity :)